# TSaveTextFileDialog and Vcl Styles

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I'm using the [TSaveTextFileDialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtDlgs.TSaveTextFileDialog) component in Delphi XE3, but when a VCL Style is enabled, the *encoding* combobox is drawn using the current VCL style.

[image: Delphi TSaveTextFileDialog]

How can I fix this, I mean disable the VCL style for the combobox?

Comment: Ooh this dialog is revolting. It doesn't even respect the Windows themes! Poor show from Emba.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parent class (TOpenTextFileDialog) of the [TSaveTextFileDialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtDlgs.TSaveTextFileDialog) component adds a set of Vcl components to implement the `Encodings` and `EncodingIndex` properties, you can disable the Vcl styles on these Vcl controls using the [`StyleElements`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.StyleElements) property.  unfortunately these components are private so you need a little hack in order to gain access and disable the Vcl Styles.

Here you have two options.

## Using a class helper.

You can introduce a helper function to get the Panel component which contains the Vcl controls of the dialog.

```
type
 TOpenTextFileDialogHelper=class helper for TOpenTextFileDialog
  function GetPanel : TPanel;
 end;

function TOpenTextFileDialogHelper.GetPanel: TPanel;
begin
  Result:=Self.FPanel;
end;
```

then you can write a method to disable the Vcl Styles, like so :

```
procedure DisableVclStyles(const Control : TControl);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if Control=nil then
    Exit;
   Control.StyleElements:=[];

  if Control is TWinControl then
    for i := 0 to TWinControl(Control).ControlCount-1 do
      DisableVclStyles(TWinControl(Control).Controls[i]);
end;
```

And finally use  on this way

```
  DisableVclStyles(SaveTextFileDialog1.GetPanel);
  SaveTextFileDialog1.Execute;
```

## RTTI

Another option is use the RTTI to access the private Vcl components.

```
var
  LRttiContext : TRttiContext;
  LRttiField :TRttiField;
begin
  LRttiContext:=TRttiContext.Create;
  for LRttiField in LRttiContext.GetType(SaveTextFileDialog1.ClassType).GetFields do
   if LRttiField.FieldType.IsInstance and LRttiField.FieldType.AsInstance.MetaclassType.ClassNameIs('TPanel') then
    DisableVclStyles(TPanel(LRttiField.GetValue(SaveTextFileDialog1).AsObject));

  SaveTextFileDialog1.Execute;
end;
```

Comment: Personally I would fix the root problem and use `IFileDialogCustomize` to customize the dialog.